# Invalid html markup

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have a html code like this

```
<ul>
  <li>Text</li><br>
  <li>Text</li><br>
</ul>
```

What I want,a line break after each li element, can be accomplished using this code. But the problem is when I go to W3C for html5 validation, it shows the error ***Element br not allowed as child of element ul in this context***.

So I understand that br cannot be used as child element of ul. What I want to know that is there any other way to get the same result as above? If it can be done in css, I am ok with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: removing breaks will result in same behaviour. lists are normally displayed in a new line.

Comment: @lichborne you're using `<br/>` to generate an empty line in html, that's not a good practice, try setting a `margin-bottom` on the list items instead

Comment: This css is working in firefox only. In chrome it has no effect at all.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `<li>` elements are `display: list-item` which will cause them to generate a block box, so you will get a break after them. Set the `display` property back to `list-item` to restore them.

If actually mean that you want a *margin*, rather than a simple line break, then use the CSS `margin` property to set one.

Comment: margin-bottom css does solve my problem but only in Firefox. In chrome it has no effect

Comment: It [works fine](http://jsbin.com/AdowIC/1/edit?html,output) in my copy of Chrome.

Comment: Did you try my example? It is important to narrow down if the problem is something to do with your install of Chrome or something to do with other code on your page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the margin-botton in css

```
ul li {
   margin-bottom: 20px; // As per your requirement
}
```

Comment: if multiple ul li are used then the same css will be applied to all.

Comment: This is a sample just to denote the way to use it. It should be modified as per the requirement of the application.

Comment: This css is working in firefox only. In chrome it has no effect at all.

Comment: Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ggRPy/. It's working fine for me on both firefox & chrome

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="one">Text</li>
   <li class="one">Text</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 <style>
        .one
        {
            line-height: 40px;
        }
 </style>
```